# Can you recommend a free service for validating a global address?

Tags: software-recommendations, api

I need an API or a database that is freely available. It should allow being included in a commercial application.

Something like Google Places API, but with better licensing terms.

Answer (score 1):

We've had some luck using the Bing API:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701713.aspx

As with the Google API there are some limitations for example a free trial will last 90 days and limit you to 50,000 addresses a day. If you're not looking for a huge volume of addresses to be matched this may suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try OSM nominatim, API is in below link :
https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/
But pay attention to **Changes to this Policy** for commercial use